# Unable to remove Azure Active-Directory due to existing Application

Tags: azure, active-directory

How to remove an orphaned Application in an Azure Directory?

I have a second (non-Default) directory that I was using to test the AD Connect app, and having finished with it, want to delete.

I have been able to remove the users both with the Management Portal and remove-msoluser, but am unable to delete the directory as it has one Application registered - "Office 365 Management APIs"

In the management console, this Application looks a little weird - there are no options to do anything on its dashboard and just checking, this Application is also installed in my Default Directory and looks the same - maybe it cannot be removed?

Have tried removing the App using the Remove-msolservice cmdlet, and tried the whole-hog approach as per Method 5 in https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2967860/en-us - seems to run through ok, but the Application is still listed, and when deleting the Directory I still get the error -

> Directory has one or more applications that were added by a user or administrator

Comment: It might be worth trying either the @AzureSupport Twitter handle or submitting an Azure support case for this. Since it's a management thing I think this would be covered under the free support just like subscription management.

Comment: Also may be worth noting that adding an application via the REST API and/or Commandlets will cause them to not show up in the Portal...could you have some hidden applications?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When performed the steps below, I could delete the Azure Active Directory tenant:

- Log in to Azure and create a new user with **Global Admin** permissions in the AAD you're trying to delete.
- Open the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell and execute the following:
  **Connect-MsolService** (Log in with @onmicrosoft global admin account you created)
  **Get-MsolServicePrincipal | Remove-MsolServicePrincipal** (This will generate errors but it's ok)
- Log in to https://manage.windowsazure.com as the **service admin**
- Delete already created @onmicrosoft.com Global Admin user
- Delete the AAD now

You check the sites below as well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2015/05/27/trouble-deleting-azure-active-directory-aad-due-to-quot-visual-studio-online-quot-item-in-aad-quot-applications-quot-list.aspx

or here:

https://www.opsgility.com/blog/deleting-azure-ad-applications

Comment: I have the impression that you cannot delete the directory right away due to a cache problem or something. I could delete directories for which I executed these steps a while ago, but could not delete the directories for wich I executed these comments a few seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the following cmdlets after running the remove cmdlets:

Get-MsolServicePrincipal | Set-MsolServicePrincipal -AccountEnabled $False

then delete the temporary global admin account (if any) and you should be able to delete the directory.

More information about this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3112170

Comment: Running this command made the deletion verification for the directory fail.

Answer (score -1):

This article helps me to delete Azure AD I created with old Windows Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgolpe/2015/04/30/walkthrough-of-deleting-an-azure-ad-tenant/

In a nutshell:

- Create a new user under the AD you intend to delete.
- User must have Global Admin role.
- You will get temporary password for this user. Once login to Azure Portal with this user, you will need to create a permanent password.
- Use this credential, you will remove Azure AD's applications using Azure AD PowerShell
- Then, go back to Azure AD you intend to delete (using your credential, not the newly created user), delete the user you just created.
- Only after doing all these will you be able to delete the Azure AD.